# What is SHA-256 in Conjunctive Normal Form?

Tags: sha-256, sha-2

What is the [conjunctive normal form (CNF)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conjunctive_normal_form) representation of $\text{SHA-256}(m)=h$, where $m$ is of fixed (or bounded) size and $h$ is 256 bit?

Comment: The equation $\text{SHA-256}(m)=h$ where $m$ is of fixed (or bounded) size, and $h$ 256-bit, **CAN** easily be written in CNF by applying the definition of SHA-256, step by step; the CNF problem resulting will not be huge. and can legitimately be considered a CNF representation of the SHA-256 algorithm. A standard CNF solver using it will compute $h$ from $m$; or a few missing bits of $m$ from the other bits and $h$.$\;$ Asking for "the simplest" such representation is not well defined (and it will likely be hard to get _the_ simplest); what's your criteria for "simple"? (please edit question)

Comment: @fgrieu I've incorporated your good suggestion into improving the question. thank you.

Comment: Dejan Jovanović and Predrag Janičić's [_Logical Analysis of Hash Functions_](http://csl.sri.com/users/dejan/papers/jovanovic-hashsat-2005.pdf#page=7)  (in Frontiers of Combining Systems, 2005) has a section on _Encoding of Hash Functions into Instances of SAT Problem_, which is what you are looking for. $\;$ Caveat: I only glanced at it; this is a pointer, not a recommendation.

Answer (score 3):

This answer was for the original question:

> What is the simplest conjunctive normal form (CNF) representation of the SHA-256 algorithm?

---

There is none. Conjunctive normal form is for Boolean formulas, which have a single truth value. SHA-256 is not a Boolean formula (SHA-256(x) is not "true" or "false.") Furthermore, CNF is only applicable if you have a fixed number of variables; this is not true for SHA-256, which has variable-length input. At best you could have 256 different formulas, each for one bit of the output, and have $2^{64}+63$ different variables in each formula.

You've probably confused decision problems with function problems. Any algorithm that returns "true" or "false" can be represented, ultimately, as a gigantic Boolean formula. Anything not just returning "true" or "false" cannot, as a Boolean formula returns only "true" or "false." While there is a $2^{64}+63+256$-variable formula that evaluates to "is $x_1\ldots x_{256}$ the SHA-256 hash of the $x_{257}\ldots x_{320}$-bit number stored in $x_{321}\ldots x_{\text{last}}$," the formula is really just one of those things that exists in theory and not in practice.

Comment: Where "in theory" is the «$2^{64}+63+256$-variable formula that evaluates to "is $x_1\ldots x_{256}$ the SHA-256 hash of the $x_{257}\ldots x_{320}$-bit number stored in $x_{321}\ldots x_{\text{last}}$»? Are there any papers or books on this? thanks

Comment: @Geremia SHA-256 supports inputs up to $2^{64}-1$ bits in length; then you add $64$ inputs because you need to know how long the message *actually* is (an input to a Boolean formula can only be 1 or 0, and so you need to supply both enough inputs for any SHA-256 input *and* enough inputs for the length of the SHA-256 input, which is an additional 64 bits). The "in theory" is "that's a **really** big formula, so you aren't going to find a version that is physically capable of being written down."

Comment: Yes, it's probably a huge formula, but where (do you know?) could I find a discussion of it? thanks

Comment: @Geremia It would be much easier to write SHA and generate the CNF using one of many tools.

Comment: @cpast: an exact equivalent to the huge CNF formula that you are considering can be written with very manageable time and size. The trick is introducing the right extra variables. See e.g. the article I link to [here](http://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/25123/555#comment57314_25123)

Comment: @fgrieu That appears to only cover a fixed input length less than the length of the output of the hash function. The huge number of variables here are absolutely required -- you *cannot* encode a generic SHA-256 input with less than $2^{64}$ variables, since there are a bare minimum of $2^{2^{64}}$ possible inputs.of maximal length (leaving aside shorter inputs). All the paper describes is SAT-equivalence, not actual equivalence.

Comment: @cpast: indeed, the CNF formula is of manageable size only for bounded message size. The CNF formula is many times as big as the message is, and about proportional to that; the number of variables also is about proportional.

Comment: This answer is tacitly wrong.  SHA256(x)==h is very clearly a decision problem and can be written as a Boolean formula in CNF form.  There are research papers on this topic and repositories on github implementing it.  Not sure how such nonsense got up voted, the system here is broken

Comment: @GregoryMorse The question did not ask about “=h” when this answer was written. That change was made at 5:59, this answer was written at 1:34.

Comment: @cpast ah indeed you are right, so this has misled me.  Indeed those 2 characters altogether change the question.  The answer here should be updated though.

Answer (score 2):

Depending on whether you use Tseitin adders or espresso logic minimization adders, SHA256 can be encoded in CNF.  The number of variables with the former would be around 100000 vs 30000 but the clauses far fewer with the former and far more with the latter.  There is a tradeoff and SAT solvers practically will work better on one or the other which must be determined experimentally as they are heuristical solvers.

The other answer here is simply wrong, there are several repositories on github with practical code generating sha256 instances.  A bit suspicious it's up voted.  Worse yet it's been done for sha256(sha256(x)).  E.g. satcoin, etc.

Its not only practically possible but used for cryptanalysis.  Granted beyond 16 or so bits the instance becomes usually harder than mere brute force.